# How can I set a percentage formula in Apache POI?

Tags: apache-poi

How can I set formula with counting percentage value in Apache POI?

And how can it make as a absolute value?

For example, if it is `-4.00%` then it converted into `4.00`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you originally have 2 cells `A1` and `B1` with numbers (in my example, these numbers are 2411 and 1333), and say the formula in cell

```
C = A1/B1
```

Try this

```
System.out.println ("formula "+ cell1.getCellFormula());

if(cell1.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
                CellValue cv = evaluator.evaluate(cell1);
                System.out.println ("cv "+ cv.formatAsString());



            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##%");
            System.out.println("Formatted as percentage "+df.format(Math.abs(cell1.getNumericCellValue())));



}
```

Output is

```
formula A1/B1

cv 1.808702175543886

Formatted as percentage 180.87%
```

Change A1 to a negative, and this will still work.

Comment: but after that how can i set 180.87% value in cell

Comment: @water: use `cell.setCellValue` and the value